# Crash on launching OFX sample app

Tags: iphone, objective-c++, ofx

I work for iPhone with OpenFeintX, I just followed the few steps to make OFX sample app work, and... it does not work.

I copied the sample folder to make another one, then I copied the OpenFeint folder and put it in the right section and I added the config files downloaded from the dashboard in the project.

When I run it, here is what I get:

```
p.p1 {margin: 0.0px 0.0px 0.0px 0.0px; font: 11.0px Menlo} span.Apple-tab-span {white-space:pre}
2011-05-19 15:02:20.416 OpenFeintX[3182:207] *** __NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x7718090 of class NSCFString autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
2011-05-19 15:02:20.418 OpenFeintX[3182:207] +[OpenFeint registerAddOn:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x22ad14
2011-05-19 15:02:20.419 OpenFeintX[3182:207] *** __NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x7718f30 of class NSCFString autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
2011-05-19 15:02:20.419 OpenFeintX[3182:207] *** __NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x7718ff0 of class NSException autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
2011-05-19 15:02:20.421 OpenFeintX[3182:207] *** __NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x771ab80 of class _NSCallStackArray autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
2011-05-19 15:02:20.422 OpenFeintX[3182:207] *** __NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x771aab0 of class _NSCallStackArray autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
2011-05-19 15:02:20.422 OpenFeintX[3182:207] *** __NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x771ac10 of class NSCFString autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
2011-05-19 15:02:20.423 OpenFeintX[3182:207] *** __NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x7835000 of class NSCFString autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
2011-05-19 15:02:20.424 OpenFeintX[3182:207] *** __NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x771aca0 of class NSConcreteMutableData autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
2011-05-19 15:02:20.522 OpenFeintX[3182:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+[OpenFeint registerAddOn:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x22ad14'

*** Call stack at first throw:

(
0   CoreFoundation                      0x02f9b919 __exceptionPreprocess + 185
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x030e95de objc_exception_throw + 47
2   CoreFoundation                      0x02f9d4eb +[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 187
3   CoreFoundation                      0x02f0d116 ___forwarding___ + 966
4   CoreFoundation                      0x02f0ccd2 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 50
5   OpenFeintX                          0x0001751d +[OFXStoreManager load] + 50
6   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x030ea9f3 call_load_methods + 187
7   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x030ed5df load_images + 85
8   ???                                 0x8fe036c8 0x0 + 2413835976
9   ???                                 0x8fe0d30a 0x0 + 2413875978
10  ???                                 0x8fe0d3d1 0x0 + 2413876177
11  ???                                 0x8fe024a9 0x0 + 2413831337
12  ???                                 0x8fe07950 0x0 + 2413853008
13  ???                                 0x8fe018b1 0x0 + 2413828273
14  ???                                 0x8fe01057 0x0 + 2413826135
)

terminate called after throwing an instance of 'NSException'
```

It does not even enter in the main...

Would anyone have a clue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, finally I managed to make it work, I don't know how... The third time I downloaded it again and tried it it was fine...

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere in the start up code the selector `+registerAddOn:` is being sent to the class `OpenFeint`.  However, `OpenFeint` does not respond to that selector.

More than that I cannot say because you haven't posted your code.

Comment: I can put the code here, but the problem is that i just launched the basic OFX sample app, which I guess is working for every body else since I did not find an answer to my question on the web... I did not write any code, I just downloaded it from Open Feint website did the needed modifications and tried to launch it... 
And it is difficult to debug since OpenFeint works as a framework, and most of the .m files are included in the framework.